# Cuando se usa 'new' y cuando no, en Java

Tags: java, poo, algoritmos, objeto, class

tengo un problema de entendimiento, cuando uso la clase ***Date*** uso '***new***' (`Date fecha = new Date();`) y cuando uso la clase ***Calendar*** ya no (`Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();`), no entiendo porque en uno si y en otro no.
Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Eso es porque la clase `Calendar` en java es abstracta, con lo que no se pueden instanciar objetos de esa clase. En cambio `Date` no lo es y puedes hacer un `new`. Cuando ejecutas `getInstance`, no te retorna un objeto de la clase `Calendar`, sino uno de una clase derivada de `Calendar` que en el calendario estándar occidental es de la clase `GregorianCalendar` con la fecha del sistema inicializada. Esta clase no es abstracta y podrías instanciar objetos de ella.

Comment: @MrDave1999 getDefaultToolkit es un singleton, getCalendar es un método fábrica estático, eso los hace totalmente diferentes

Comment: @MrDave1999 sin embargo eso es una mala concepción, ya que puedes usar un constructor protected con Calendar, eso los hace totalmente diferentes, te invito a revisar el código y retirar tu voto de cierre en caso de cambiar tu opinión.

Answer (score 2):

Si observas la [el código de clase Calendar](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java) verás que es una clase abstracta.

Sin embargo puedes obtener instancias mediante:

- sus constructores protected
- sus métodos fábrica estáticos

El motivo de este diseño de clases no es casualidad, sino parte de la evolución de lenguaje Java.

Bueno, lo primero a aclarar es que en este caso, a diferencia de Toolkit a pesar de que los métodos se llaman `getInstance` no obtienen un singleton [como en el caso de Toolkit](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/45af329463a45955ea2759b89cb0ebfe40570c3f/jdk/src/share/classes/java/awt/Toolkit.java#L883), y esto en Calendar se puede comprobar fácilmente mediante:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance() == Calendar.getInstance())
```

La segunda aclaración importante es que los métodos estáticos de fabrica **no son lo mismo** que el patrón de diseño Fabrica.

### ¿Que beneficios y problemas nos daría usar el constructor o los métodos fábrica?

Como te podrás haber imaginado, el uso de una clase abstracta no es casualidad, nos permite tener los elementos mínimos para operar un calendario y por ello el constructor es de tipo `protected`, para que los distintos subtipos de calendario puedan refinar la definición de un calendario.

Al usar el método `getInstance` de tu preferencia, si bien no obtienes un singleton, tus instancias se cachean a partir de Java 1.8 [según su documentación](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/569b1b644416/src/share/classes/java/util/Locale.java).

Ahora... un poco más abstracto como tu pregunta, Si revisas el libro **Effective Java** escrito por Joshua Bloch en su capítulo 2 (creación y destrucción de objetos) nos sugiere usar métodos fábrica en vez de constructores basado en los siguientes argumentos:

- Los métodos fábrica tienen nombres, por ejemplo es más útil ver en tu código un `BigInteger.probableprime` que un `new BigInteger(2,2,new Java.util.Random())`.
- A diferencia de los constructores no es necesario que creen un nuevo objeto cada vez (como en la implementación de Java 8 de `Calendar`, lo obtiene desde caché si ya existe, y lo mismo sucede con `Boolean.valueof`)
- A diferencia de los constructores pueden regresar cualquier subtipo de la clase actual.
- reducen la verbosidad en la creación de instancias parametrizadas (osea con genéricos)

Ahora si te preguntas por qué además de fábricas `Calendar` tiene constructor, posiblemente sea porque el mismo autor entre las desventajas que señala en únicamente usar métodos estáticos de fábrica están:

- Si la clase no tiene acceso público o protegido, no puedes crear subclases (aunque esto favorece al uso de composición sobre herencia)
- Que es difícil sin conocimiento previo distinguir sus métodos de cualquier otro método estático o incluso saber lo que es únicamente por el nombre.

Por convención, algunos nombres comunes con lo que podrás hallar métodos estáticos de fábrica son:

- valueOf
- of
- getInstance
- newInstance
- getType
- newType

Answer (score 0):

Calendar es una clase abstracta, y por tanto no se puede instanciar de la manera que tu dices, si no sabes lo que es una clase o un método abstracto, te recomiendo que te pases por este link:

https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=668:clases-y-metodos-abstractos-en-java-abstract-class-clases-del-api-ejemplos-codigo-y-ejercicios-cu00695b&catid=68&Itemid=188