# Construir Map con Map interno desde una lista

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Tengo una clase que describe una ciudad, esta clase tiene tres campos de los cuales uno de ellos es el código del país

```
public class Ciudad{
  private String codigoPais;
  private String codigo;
  private String nombre;

  //getters y setters
}
```

Tengo un método que a partir de una `lista` de Ciudades contruye un `mapa` donde la clave (`key`) es el código del país y el valor (`value`) es un `mapa` de las ciudades que pertenecen al mismo país

```
public class MapStream {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Ciudad> ciudades = new ArrayList<>();
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("57", "1", "Bogota"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("57", "2", "Medellin"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("58", "3", "Bucaramanga"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("58", "4", "Cali"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("59", "1", "Pereira"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("59", "2", "Ibague"));
    ciudades.add(new Ciudad("70", "10", "Cartagena"));
        
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapCiudades = construirMapaCiudades(ciudades);
  }

  public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> construirMapaCiudades(List<Ciudad> ciudades){
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
      Map<String, String> tempCiudades;
      for(Ciudad ciudad : ciudades){
        tempCiudades = !map.containsKey(ciudad.getCodigoPais()) ? new HashMap<>() : map.get(ciudad.getCodigoPais());
        tempCiudades.put(ciudad.getCodigo(), ciudad.getNombre());
        map.put(ciudad.getCodigoPais(), tempCiudades);
      }
      return map;
    }
}
```

La salida de este código es la siguiente

```
{57={1=Bogota, 2=Medellin}, 58={3=Bucaramanga, 4=Cali}, 59={1=Pereira, 2=Ibague}, 70={10=Cartagena}}
```

Como se observa existe un país (57) con un mapa de dos ciudades.

He mirado ejemplos donde a partir de la `lista` de ciudades se construye un `Map<String, String>` usando `stream`

```
Map<String, String> mapCiudades = ciudades.stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Ciudad::getCodigo, Ciudad::getNombre));
```

Mi pregunta es, hay una manera de simplificar el código del método `construirMapaCiudades` haciendo uso de `stream` y que de la misma salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede simplificar un poco la lógica usando colectores y la fábrica estática de la interfaz Map de la isguiente manera:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> construirMapaCiudades(List<Ciudad> ciudades) {
    return ciudades.stream().distinct()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            (a) -> a.getCodigoPais(),
                            (b) -> Map.of(b.getCodigo(), b.getNombre()))
            );
}
```

El colector recibe dos `Function`, una para la creación de la llave y otra para la creación del valor, aquí simplificamos al ser Function una interfaz funcional usamos la notación de lambda en ambos casos.

Respecto a los métodos fábrica, como en el caso de `Map.of`, te recomiendo revisar [esta otra respuesta mía al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/361298/342).

Tanto a como b se refieren a el elemento actual de la lista de ciudades.

Esta implementación asume que no hay países duplicados.

### Con países duplicados

Asumiendo que hay países duplicados como en tu ejemplo, procederíamos a usar un colector de agrupación, para mezclar los duplicados de paises primero, especificando que queremos agrupar por el código de país.

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> construirMapaCiudades2(List<Ciudad> ciudades) {
    return ciudades.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    (ciudad) -> ciudad.getCodigoPais(),
                    Collectors.toMap((ciudad) -> ciudad.getCodigo(), (ciudad) -> ciudad.getNombre())
            )
    );
}
```

Para que no nos quede del lado derecho del mapa toda la entidad completa le pasamos como segundo parámetro otro colector que nos servirá como si fuera un típico mapper. Nuestro segundo parámetro debe ser un colector y no una función como ne el caso anterior; a este segundo coletor se le denomina **downstream collector**, y [los tutoriales de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) lo definen como:

> El parámetro Collector se le llama downstream collector. Se trata de
> un colector en el que el entorno de ejecución de Java se aplica tras
> obtener los resultados de otro colector. (traducción mía)

No intentes remplazarlo por la función `(b) -> Map.of(b.getCodigo(), b.getNombre()))` o te dará error.

Así que podríamos dejar tu programa en:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question370613;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Ciudad> ciudades = Arrays.asList(
                new Ciudad("57", "1", "Bogota"),
                new Ciudad("57", "2", "Medellin"),
                new Ciudad("58", "3", "Bucaramanga"),
                new Ciudad("58", "4", "Cali"),
                new Ciudad("59", "1", "Pereira"),
                new Ciudad("59", "2", "Ibague"),
                new Ciudad("70", "10", "Cartagena")
        );

        System.out.println(construirMapaCiudadesOriginal(ciudades));
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println(construirMapaCiudades2(ciudades));
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> construirMapaCiudadesOriginal(List<Ciudad> ciudades) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> tempCiudades;
        for (Ciudad ciudad : ciudades) {
            tempCiudades = !map.containsKey(ciudad.getCodigoPais()) ? new HashMap<>() : map.get(ciudad.getCodigoPais());
            tempCiudades.put(ciudad.getCodigo(), ciudad.getNombre());
            map.put(ciudad.getCodigoPais(), tempCiudades);
        }
        return map;
    }
    
    public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> construirMapaCiudades2(List<Ciudad> ciudades) {
        Map map = ciudades.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        (ciudad) -> ciudad.getCodigoPais(),
                        Collectors.toMap((ciudad) -> ciudad.getCodigo(), (ciudad) -> ciudad.getNombre())
                )
        );
         
        
        return map;
    }
}
```

Como podrías esperar la salida siempre será igual en los dos métodos produciendo:

> {57={1=Bogota, 2=Medellin}, 58={3=Bucaramanga, 4=Cali}, 59={1=Pereira, 2=Ibague}, 70={10=Cartagena}}
>
> ---
>
> {57={1=Bogota, 2=Medellin}, 58={3=Bucaramanga, 4=Cali}, 59={1=Pereira, 2=Ibague}, 70={10=Cartagena}}

Comment: Gracias por responder, e implementado el código y genera un error de llave duplicada, esto seguramente por que puede existir varias ciudades del mismo país. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 57 (attempted merging values {1=Bogota} and {2=Medellin}` en mi código `57`el el código de país

Comment: Actualizado, pero para que funcione igual debes de agregar equals y hash map a tu clase `Ciudad`

Comment: Realice los cambios que me sugiere pero no funciona, persiste el error, funciona cuando los métodos hash e equals estan unicamente con el campo pais, cuando se hace con los campos pasis y codigo se presenta el error.

Comment: Se me olvido comentar que cuando hago el hash y el equals unicamente con el campo de codigoPais, si en la lista existen dos ciudades del mismo país solo deja una en el Map interno

Comment: @isaac entonces deberás modificar la pregunta si quieres que funcione con tu función hash agregándle un ejemplo de datos de entrada y de salida, pues con loa información que proporcionaste este es le código que puedo regalarte de momento.

Comment: Agradezco de su colaboración, me doy cuenta que era necesario colocar los datos de ejemplo, gracias por mencionarlo, igualmente por su tiempo en ayudarme. La pregunta fue editada con código ejemplo y salida esperada

Comment: @isaac listo, si la respuesta te fué útil te sugiero darle click a la flecha arriba, si resolvió tu problema la paloma al lado de la respuesta. Saludos.