# Error "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Cliente"

Tags: java, sql, jsp

lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en esto y estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto de desarrollo web en capas. Mi problema es en la capa persistencia el cual salta el error mencionado en el titulo: "incompatible types:  String cannot be converted to Cliente". Específicamente al implementar el método buscar en la Reserva.

```
   @Override
public Reserva buscar(String num) {
    String sql = "select * from reserva where num='" + num + "'";
    Object[] fila = Operacion.buscar(sql);
    if (fila != null) {
        Reserva res = new Reserva(fila[0].toString(), fila[1].toString(), fila[2].toString(), Double.parseDouble(fila[3].toString()),fila[4].toString(),fila[5].toString());
        return res;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Pues eso, no puedo convertir la fila 4 y fila 5 a String siendo estos de tipo Cliente y Empleado respectivamente. Por lo tanto, no puedo realizar ninguna búsqueda por numero de reserva.

Aquí la clase reserva y su constructor.

```
public class Reserva {
private String num,fec,est;
private Cliente cli;
private Empleado emp;
private double tot,porDes;
private List list;

public Reserva() {
    list=new ArrayList();
}

public Reserva(String num, String fec, String est, double tot, Cliente cli, Empleado emp) {
    this.num = num;
    this.fec = fec;
    this.est = est;
    this.tot = tot;
    this.cli = cli;
    this.emp = emp;
}
```

Agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Comment: Que retorna la fila 4 y 5? Un id? o el objeto como cadena de texto?

Comment: Así es Zerocool, la fila 4 retorna una id de tipo String de la clase cliente y la fila 5 retorna un codigo de tipo String de la clase Empleado, aparte estas clases tienen otros atributos todos String.

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque en tu constructor el quinto elemento es un objeto de tipo `Cliente`.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Modificas el constructor de `Reserva` para que acepte cadenas en vez de los últimos dos objetos
2. Modificas tu método buscar para que mande un Objeto en vez de `fila[4].toString()` y `fila[5].toString()`

PD: Si quieres hacer algo muy elegante podrías hacer un método fábrica estático de `Cliente` y `Empleado` para que tu código quedara algo como:

```
 Reserva res = new Reserva(fila[0].toString(), fila[1].toString(), fila[2].toString(), Double.parseDouble(fila[3].toString()),Cliente.fromString(fila[4].toString()),Empleado.fromString(fila[5].toString()));
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero no tengo idea de como hacer un método fabrica estático de cliente y empleado, si me guiaras serias de gran ayuda Ruslan López.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer más al respecto en esta respuesta mía: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/361298/342

Comment: Y aquí tienes un ejemplo muy concreto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/401721/342

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que no puedes convertir esos valores a Cliente y Empleado ya que bueno una cadena (string con el id de cliente) no es un Cliente per se y pasa lo mismo con el código de empleado. Es como decir que con nada más tu nombre te podemos crear lo que no es cierto.

Para que lo tengas sencillo lo que puedes hacer es una vez que tienes esos datos haces otras dos consultas en la base de datos buscando a Cliente y Empleado, luego creas como tal al Cliente usando los valores del retorno de la consulta y de la misma manera haces con Empleado, al final creas la Reserva cuando ya tienes todo disponible, algo como:

```
@Override
public Reserva buscar(String num) {
    String sql = "select * from reserva where num='" + num + "'";
    Object[] fila = Operacion.buscar(sql);
    if (fila != null) {
        //se obtuvo la reserva, se busca Cliente y Empleado
        //buscando Cliente
        sql = "select * from cliente where id='" + fila[4].toString() + "'";
        Object[] fila2 = Operacion.buscar(sql);
        Cliente cliente = null;
        if(fila2 != null){
          //aca estoy suponiendo que el cliente tiene dos campos id y nombre
          cliente = new Cliente(fila2[0].toString(),fila2[1].toString())
        }
        
        //buscando Empleado
        sql = "select * from empleado where codigo='" + fila[5].toString() + "'";
        Object[] fila3 = Operacion.buscar(sql);
        Empleado empleado = null;
        if(fila3 != null){
          //aca estoy suponiendo que el empleado tiene dos campos codigo y nombre
          empleado = new Empleado(fila3[0].toString(),fila3[1].toString())
        }

        //Nota: si de casualidad al buscar empleado o cliente no se encuentra alguno queda el objeto como nulo entonces la reserva quedaría con cliente o empleado nulo, sería tenerlo en cuenta y validar esas cosas en caso de...

        Reserva res = new Reserva(fila[0].toString(), fila[1].toString(), fila[2].toString(), Double.parseDouble(fila[3].toString()),cliente,empleado);
        return res;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Saludos!